# Debug arbitrary function in IPython notebook

Tags: debugging, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to debug a function I write in IPython notebook. I tried to use magic `%debug` and `%%debug` with a statement, but they do not break at all. I searched the whole Internet and most of them recommends modifying the function definition and insert `pdb` or `ipdb` or `IPython.core.debugger.Tracer` function calls at the break site. But since I am trying to debug an object method, the modification won't affect any currently created objects. I would have to create those objects again, possibly an expensive process, in order to debug one of its methods. Are there better ways?